# Conjugacy of Cartan subalgebras

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

This is probabably a very silly question, stemming from some fundamental misunderstanding I have of the relevant definitions, but I am stumped by it.

I know that any two Cartan subalgebras of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ should be conjugate. I understand this to mean in particular that there is $g\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ such that
$$\mathrm{Ad}(g)\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&-1
\end{pmatrix}=
g
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
g^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

This seems impossible, though, as these matrices have different characteristic polynomials.

What have I misunderstood?

Comment: You made a confusion between lines (1-dimensional Lie subalgebras) and elements of the lines. To say that two lines are conjugated doesn't mean any two of their elements are conjugated (but means that some nonzero element of the 1st line is conjugate to some element of the second line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the fact that $Ad(g)\pmatrix{1& 0\cr 0&-1}$ maybe $i\pmatrix{0 &1\cr -1&0}$ which has the same characteristic polynomial than $\pmatrix{1& 0\cr 0&-1}$

take $g={\sqrt2\over 2}\pmatrix{1&-i\cr -i&1}$.

Comment: But the diagonal matrices of trace zero are a maximal toral subalgebra, and for semisimple Lie algebras maximal toral subalgebras are Cartan subalgebras, aren't they? I also don't see what your calculation has to do with $\mathfrak{h}$ not being self-normalizing, as $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is not in the vector space generated by $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$.